# Distinguishable tetrahedral dice

Tags: abstract-algebra

Problem:

Find the number of distinguishable tetrahedral dice that can be made using one, two, three, and four
dots on the faces of a regular tetrahedron.

---

Approach:

I used the formula $$r = \dfrac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} |X_g|$$
My initial thoughts were using 3 rotations for each 4 sides which gives 12 elements.
$X = 4!$ since we have 1,2,3,4 dots. This yields to $r = 2$.

I am wondering if my approach is correct since it looks too easy :)

---

The hint tells to consider $S_4$ or $A_4$ actions on tetrahedron.
Please help!

Comment: If the dots are on the faces, how do you decide which value a roll indicates? The unseen (face-down) value, I suppose?

Comment: @Travis: yes, face-down

Answer (score 1):

Your problem statement is unclear, but I interpret it to mean:  How many distinguishable tetrahedral dice can be made in which the numbers 1 through 4 must appear on a side?

The numbers 1 and 2 must always be on adjacent sides.  The 3 can appear in one of two remaining (distinguishable) sides, and the four on the remaining side.

Thus only two distinguishable dice.